# VSIX: is there a better way than this to get the Visual Studio Active Document?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm upgrading my old set of Visual Studio tools to work with the new extensibility framework.  When I use the new templates, I get a clean set of references that only requires **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0** and **NewtonSoft.Json**.  Then I start pulling in my old code.  The first thing I try to do is get the environment that the custom command is running in.  I use this code:

```
    // The VS Package provides services for examining the Visual Studio environment.
    InsertModuleHeaderCommand.serviceProvider = package as IServiceProvider;
    InsertModuleHeaderCommand.environment = InsertModuleHeaderCommand.serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
    Assumes.Present(InsertModuleHeaderCommand.environment);
```

And at this point I need to pull in **envdte** and **envdte80**. Then I get a message about cleaning up the interops.  This just looks ugly and old.  Is there a better, newer way to get the **ActiveDocument**?

Comment: Just add EnvDTE100 (the latest) as a nuget package. Everything is a package now.

Comment: Yeah, that was a step in the right direction.  Sorry I couldn't vote for it an an answer.